# converting exponential value to BigDecimal or Long using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java API, where input usually have decimal values. But long numbers are in exponential form.
Some of the values are in exponential form and some are in decimal. Sample input string:

> {aaData:[["1996-04-12",4.0872E8],["1996-04-15",7.92192E7],["1996-04-16",4.8016E7],["1996-04-17",4.2816E7],["1996-04-18",2.72688E7],["1996-04-19",1.29136E7],["1996-04-22",8041600.0],["1996-04-23",4297600.0],["1996-04-24",7795200.0],["1996-04-25",1.94784E7]]}

I need to convert all the values to decimal values.
On UI side, JQuery is handling this conversion.  Is it possible to do this at backend, with Gson or any other library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do in Java code. You don't need to use another library, because the E notation is supported by the built-in `java.math.BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("4.0872E8");
long value = d.longValue();
System.out.println(value); // 408720000
```

Comment: Json string structure is not uniform, it changes with each request. Due to data volume I can not  iterate through each entry and handle conversion.

I have asked upstream developer to do BigDecimal conversion. That might solve my problem permanently. Thanks.